# I want to update a table based on 3 column values in a MSSql table. However I keep receiving Ann error message "incorrect syntax near ProductSource"

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
update BigTable
    set Quantity=7
    where ProductName= 'Apple Juice' ProductSource='AS_1' and Type='Crate'
```

Comment: You are missing an `AND` or `OR` between the first two conditions.  I view this as a simple typographical error and have voted to close.

Comment: I tried; update BigTable set Quantity=7  where ProductName= 'Apple Juice', ProductSource='AS_1' ,and Type='Crate'

Comment: Also: update BigTable set Quantity=7  where ProductName= 'Apple Juice' and ProductSource='AS_1' and Type='Crate'    still with no success

Comment: That code I've tried already.  Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you definitely need to put AND after 'Apple Juice' _put_AND_here ProductSource='AS_1' as Gordon Linoff suggests.

Then if this doesn't work you need to check the ProductSource column spelling, maybe you have a typo in the actual column name. Please, post the complete schema of the BigTable table.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
update BigTable set
  Quantity = 7
where 
  ( ProductName = 'Apple Juice' )
  and ( ProductSource = 'AS_1' )
  and ( Type='Crate' )
```

If this, updates nothing run:

```
Select
  Count(*)
From
  BigTable 
where 
  ( ProductName = 'Apple Juice' )
  and ( ProductSource = 'AS_1' )
  and ( Type='Crate' )
```

to verify that there are rows to update.

Comment: Thanks that did the job. Actually I had a column of type text. I simply aligned it with the others to type varchar and three code was ok.